# SPROC with Outer-Apply returns too many rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, outer-apply

I have a complicated enough SPROC, which I modified to return a few more columns (from additional tables).

What I wanted is to have this SPROC still to return the same amount of rows and the same data, but to fill in new columns (if data exists) as well, for those rows.
My modification does fill new columns, but also returns more rows (based on the values it finds those additional tables).

Here is a sample of the additional table:

Table FCB:

| FCBID | InvoiceID | FCBIDCode | CBCode | IsSet | FCBJrnID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC1 | 718 | abcC1 | cb1 | 0 | 1234 |
| ABC2 | 718 | abcC2 | cb1 | 0 | 1234 |
| ABC3 | 718 | abcC3 | cb1 | 0 | 1234 |
| DEF1 | 718 | abcC4 | cb1 | 0 | 1234 |
| DEF2 | 718 | abcC5 | cb1 | 0 | 1234 |
| DEF3 | 718 | abcC6 | cb1 | 0 | 1234 |
| BBB2 | 334 | abcC7 | cb2 | 1 | 3333 |
| AAA5 | 225 | abcC8 | cb3 | 0 | 4444 |

Table Invoices:

| InvoiceID | ProdID | TrackNum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 334 | P4 | T7 |
| 718 | P1 | T1 |
| 718 | P2 | T1 |
| 225 | P5 | T5 |
| 225 | P6 | T6 |
| 718 | P3 | T1 |
| 718 | P9 | T1 |
| 718 | P3 | T2 |
| 718 | P9 | T2 |
| 718 | P1 | T2 |
| 718 | P2 | T2 |

Table FCBAP:

| FCBID | ProdID | TrackNum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC1 | P1 | T1 |
| ABC2 | P2 | T1 |
| ABC3 | P3 | T1 |
| DEF1 | P1 | T2 |
| DEF2 | P2 | T2 |
| DEF3 | P3 | T2 |
| BBB2 | P4 | T3 |

The original SPROC (the main part of it) is around the InvoiceID and ProdID, and when I did execute the original SPROC it returned me only 2 rows (the correct behaviour).
I.e. Search by InvoiceID = 718

| InvoiceID | ProdID |
| --- | --- |
| 718 | P1 |
| 718 | P2 |
| 718 | P3 |
| 718 | P9 |

I have added the following parts to this SPROC:

Added columns into the Main Query:

```
[FCBI].[FCBID],
[FCBI].[FCBIDCode],
[FCBI].[CBCode],
```

And I added another Outer Apply part, to take data from additional tables:

```
OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT
            [FCB].[FCBID],
            [FCB].[FCBIDCode],
            [LTC].[FieldText] AS [CBCode]
        FROM [dbo].[FCB] AS [FCB]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[GenericCodes] AS [GRC] ON [GRC].[Guid] = [FCB].[CBCode]
        CROSS APPLY [dbo].[GetTranslationTable] (@LanguageCode , [GRC].[DescriptionID]) AS [LTC]
        WHERE
            [FCB].[InvoiceID] = [MT].[InvoiceID]
            AND FCB.IsSet = 0
            AND FCB.FCBJrnID = MT.FCBJrnID
    ) AS [FCBI];
```

What I expect to be returned in this case:

| InvoiceID | ProdID | FCBID | FCBIDCode | CBCode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 718 | P1 | ABC1 | abcC1 | cb1 |
| 718 | P2 | ABC2 | abcC2 | cb1 |
| 718 | P3 | ABC3 | abcC3 | cb1 |
| 718 | P9 |  |  |  |

But what I'm getting instead is:

| InvoiceID | ProdID | FCBID | FCBIDCode | CBCode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 718 | P1 | ABC1 | abcC1 | cb1 |
| 718 | P2 | ABC2 | abcC2 | cb1 |
| 718 | P3 | ABC3 | abcC3 | cb1 |
| 718 | P1 | DEF1 | abcC4 | cb1 |
| 718 | P2 | DEF2 | abcC5 | cb1 |
| 718 | P3 | DEF3 | abcC6 | cb1 |
| 718 | P9 |  |  |  |

Comment: Are you sure you want an outer apply and not a join? You can see the issue right? You're getting multiple `FCBID` values which when using an outer apply multiples your rows. In fact based on your sample data you just want to avoid returning any values starting `DEF`... Although the DEF rows are definitely associated with invoice 718, so what is the premise for excluding them? You need to be clear on the data you want before we can assist.

Comment: I tried a few different approaches with it. But still cannot figure out what should I do (No, sorry I do not see where the issue is exactly). The table has more data and the SPROC is going thru quite a few other tables to get the data. In the current sample, it needs only ABC1/2/3, but in other it could be different.

Comment: Forget the approached, you need to explain how the data is related, i.e. why the DEF rows should be excluded because as your question stands they should be returned, you haven't explained why not. And if there is a relationship between the FCBID table and the invoice table you should be using a join rather than an apply. If you build it up slowly... one table at a time, you'll see where it goes wrong. But banging a great big cross apply on is too much to debug in one go.

Comment: I have updated the Invoice table. I suspected that without giving more details on the original SPROC and tables involved - it might be hard to provide help on this. (but decided to give it a shot anyway).

Comment: On the contrary you should be able to create a [MRE] and in doing so you're probably work out the issue and solve it yourself :)

Comment: Thanks Dale. Let me try that :)

Comment: Updating your invoice table doesn't help - you still haven't explained why the DEF codes shouldn't be being displayed. You need to clarify the relationship such that we understand how you are trying to pull the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever it worth, and in case it will be clear to anyone looking into this later, the solution was to change the OUTER APPLY block as following:

```
OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT
            [FCB].[FCBID],
            [FCB].[FCBIDCode],
            [LTC].[FieldText] AS [CBCode]
        FROM [dbo].[FCBAP] AS [FCBAP]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[FCB] AS [FCB] ON [FCB].[FCBID] = [FCBAP].[FCBID]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[GenericCodes] AS [GRC] ON [GRC].[Guid] = [FCB].[CBCode]
        CROSS APPLY [dbo].[GetTranslationTable] (@LanguageCode , [GRC].[DescriptionID]) AS [LTC]
        WHERE
            [FCBAP].[ProdID] = [MT].[ProdID]
            AND [FCBAP].[TrackNumb] = [MT].[TrackNum]
            [FCB].[InvoiceID] = [MT].[InvoiceID]
            AND FCB.IsSet = 0
            AND FCB.FCBJrnID = MT.FCBJrnID
    ) AS [FCBI];
```